# Assigning incompatible type to a delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uipopovercontroller

Environment: Xcode Version 6.0 (6A254o) running iOS 8.0 SDK

I'm attempting to assign the main UIViewController (presenting controller) as the delegate to the presented popup UIViewController:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "OrangeViewController.h"
#import "MessageViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController () <UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate>{
    OrangeViewController *orangeVC;
    MessageViewController *msgVC;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *helpBarItem;

@end

    @implementation MainViewController
    ...    
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIPopoverPresentationController *msgPC = [msgVC popoverPresentationController];
        msgPC.barButtonItem = self.helpBarItem;
        msgPC.delegate = self; <-- incompatible type
        msgPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
        msgVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(260.0, 240.0);
    }
```

However I'm getting an incompatible assignment for the delegate:

[image]

> ...MainViewController.m:40:20: Assigning to
>   'id' from incompatible type
>   'MainViewController *const __strong'

How do I change the MainViewController (self) from 'const-strong' to what's compatible with the UIPopover view controller (or via the best solution)?

Comment: Please check if your MainViewController class conforms to <UIPopoverControllerDelegate> protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I had accidentally used the wrong  declaration.

I noticed this when I had edited by post with the added screen shot of the wrong  statement.

The correct :

[image]

...verses the INCORRECT

```
<UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `MainViewController`'s interface file (or in an extension in your implementation file) you should declare that MainViewController implements the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` protocol.

You can do something like this in your MainViewController.m:

```
@interface MainViewController () < UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate >
@end
```

or, in MainViewController.h, you can include that `< UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate >` after the main `@interface MainViewController`.  I usually put the protocol declaration in the header only if I want external classes to know that my class implements the protocol.

**Edit:** In your updated question it looks like you already had the right idea with declaring that MainViewController implemented a protocol, but you didn't use the right one.  MainViewController should implement `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`, not `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate`.  `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` inherits from `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` but that delegate property you're assigning wants `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` specifically, not `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate`.

Comment: I already have that:  @interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate>.   ...yet still have the warning.

Comment: Ah, we're both mistaken, I think.  The protocol you want to implement is `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`, which inherits from `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate`, but `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` is not "enough."